# How to change higher education standards?

Tags: graduate-school, education

I discovered a new field of mathematics.

I have the ambitious wish to include it into college standard programs.

Who makes the standards? How the standards work? Which procedure one needs to follow to change the standards?

How to make my new field of math into college standards?

---

My question received two downvotes. Why? It may be very hard to do in practice. But my questions is quite valid as a theoretical issue, independently on whether I can implement it in practice.

---

There was proposed that my question was answered in [I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18491/1637).

It is not so: My question is unlike that question not about acceptance by community but about how standards (documents, not just opinions) setting higher education standards are managed (who writes them, who votes for them, etc.) Maybe I have not made it enough clear, but my question is about documents not people (while that other question is about *people*).

Comment: Since you're asking why the downvotes: the sheer arrogance of this question is why I downvoted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18491/i-believe-i-have-solved-a-famous-open-problem-how-do-i-convince-people-in-the-f)

Comment: @shoover It is not a duplicate. Convincing people that one solved a famous problem has nothing to do with education standards. My question, even if I haven't stressed this enough, is about education standards, not about acceptance by community in general

Comment: @MorganRodgers I try to explain that the question (at least how I had it in mind) was not about convincing people but about the formal procedures to get my course into the relevant document (not how to convince the document writers, but about the procedure)

Comment: This question is based on a false premise. No higher education standard lists tge courses taught in academia.

Answer (score 3):

So you've discovered a new field of mathematics. Congratulations. But results don't usually jump from research level to college level immediately: the new field takes time to be explored, confirmed, and understood. If your mathematician peers think it's worth teaching, they'll eventually start teaching it. Eventually. This can take years or even decades, e.g. see [this comic](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/how-math-works).

As for who makes the standards: they arise by consensus. There's a reasonably well-defined set of ideas that everyone agrees an undergraduate should know (see [examples for physics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109397/is-an-undergraduate-physics-degree-the-same-everywhere-in-terms-of-coursework/109422#109422)). To insert your new field into college syllabus, you must convince your peers that it's correct, interesting, relevant, etc.

Comment: My question is specifically about the standards. Do you mean that there is no international higher education standard set by some nonprofit association, but just informal (not written as a certain document) "consensus" of different countries?

Comment: You tried to convince me that it does not happens quickly. No need to convince, I know this. Maybe it will take 40 years without me actively working on this and 39 years if I receive a proper answer to my question and start actively work on promotion of my research into education standards

Comment: @porton there is no nonprofit association that sets standards, yes.

Comment: add that there is no such organization to your answer, so that I could accept it as the proper answer

Comment: That  is  correct  ,  that  there is NO international   committee   or  any  committee  in  the  United   States  that  sets  educational  standards.  for higher  education.  This  is  especially  true  in  the  United  States   since  the    the  united  states  has  public,  private   AND  religiously   affiliated    universities   ,  colleges  and  schools..   i   attended  religiously  affiliated  private   schools   and  went  to  a  college  of   a private university.   and  graduated  twice. There  is NO  international  committee   setting   higher  educations  "standards."